# Deployment war file on Azure

Tags: azure, web-services, tomcat, war

When i put my war file on D:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps and restart my app, no directory are create
Do you have some solutions ?

Logs of deployment:

```
2021-03-22T11:42:58.0110686Z,Updating submodules.,1bd3e5b1-47f2-46ce-9457-f22ade6578aa,0
2021-03-22T11:42:58.0891711Z,Preparing deployment for commit id 'c6e8c194dd'.,0e358782-a7e2-489c-a948-8d092e2167bb,0
2021-03-22T11:42:58.3235865Z,Generating deployment script.,f5b0c67e-46f7-462d-8910-d82e86d2d6ca,0
    2021-03-22T11:42:58.3704629Z,Using cached version of deployment script (command: 'azure -y --no-dot-deployment -r "D:\home\site\repository" -o "D:\home\site\deployments\tools" --basic --sitePath "D:\home\site\repository"').,,0
2021-03-22T11:42:58.4016684Z,Running deployment command...,c4320046-f4d1-4886-8e7b-bd831740e0d4,0
    2021-03-22T11:42:58.4172963Z,Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd",,0
    2021-03-22T11:42:59.9329442Z,Handling Basic Web Site deployment.,,0
    2021-03-22T11:43:01.1360454Z,Creating app_offline.htm,,0
    2021-03-22T11:43:01.1516687Z,KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot',,0
    2021-03-22T11:43:01.1516687Z,Copying file: 'bin\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\webapps\sapws.war',,0
    2021-03-22T11:43:01.1672937Z,Deleting app_offline.htm,,0
    2021-03-22T11:43:01.1672937Z,Finished successfully.,,0
2021-03-22T11:43:01.2297946Z,Running post deployment command(s)...,24cd4f28-8e09-4dd3-884f-7a78ac72e1cb,0
2021-03-22T11:43:01.3079454Z,Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).,24b334b7-e6c1-428f-a9ac-d91f039188c6,0
2021-03-22T11:43:01.4172916Z,Deployment successful.,9512433d-cee0-45c2-a8fe-4bf173281d0b,0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method in my gif to test and deploy.

***You also can use below way to deploy webapp.***

[Deploy your app to Azure App Service with a ZIP or WAR file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip)

[image]

Comment: I try before to do that but all time i can't and get a msg "Put files on wwwroot" even if i'm in the good directory.

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ? @TiziToure